# Books about stream ciphers

Tags: encryption, rc4

I am new to ciphers and for my assignment i have to implement a stream cipher algorithm without libraries (on my own). So my question is: Does anyone know about any GOOD books which have examples and explanation of implementation?

Comment: Wikipedia may be a good enough starting point. For example, the current page on [Salsa20 and ChaCha20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) provides examples and implementations. And, by the way, these stream ciphers are a better choice than RC4 (I let you find why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The coverage in books is lighter than that for block ciphers, but there are a few excellent books out there.

Two classics: *Analysis and Design of Stream Ciphers* by R. Rueppel and *Stability Theory of Stream Ciphers*, Ding, Xiao and Shan.

Very theoretical, wonderful: *Stream Ciphers and Number Theory*, Cusick, Dai and Renvall.

There are newer books by Klein, Maitra, Robshaw as well. These consider more modern designs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably all you need to know about RC4 (at your level) is on the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4). There's even code. And then there are all the links to follow for more detail. And two books in Further Reading:-

1. Paul, Goutam; Subhamoy Maitra (2011). RC4 Stream Cipher and Its Variants. CRC Press. ISBN 9781439831359.
2. Schneier, Bruce (1995). "Chapter 17 – Other Stream Ciphers and Real Random-Sequence Generators". Applied Cryptography: Protocols, Algorithms, and Source Code in C (2nd ed.). Wiley. ISBN 978-0471117094.

Make sure you acknowledge the [Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) section on that page.